# AppendChild in for loop adds every second child?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, wrapper, children, appendchild

I need to wrap children element in wrap-of-parent. Before wraping add some attributes to parent and child elements. In the code described below, everything works well if the children are one below the other in a separate row, and if they are in one row, every other child is inserted into the wrap-of-parent. Why is this happening and how to fix it?

I get:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="parent1">
    <div id="child1"></div>
    <div id="child2"></div>
    <div id="wrap-of-parent1">
        <div id="child3"></div>
        <div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to get:

```
<div id="container">
<div id="parent1">
    <div id="wrap-of-parent1">   
        <div id="child1"></div>
        <div id="child2"></div>
        <div id="child3"></div>
        <div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```js
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   const parentDivs = container.querySelectorAll(":scope *"); //if child elements also have child elements, to wrap in
 
     for (let parent of parentDivs) {
     // create a new div
     let wrap = document.createElement('div');
     wrap.id = 'wrap-of-' + parent.id;
      // move the parent's children to it
     let children = parent.childNodes;
     
     for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
     if (children[i].nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
         children[i].setAttribute("data", "somedata");
         wrap.append(children[i]);
     }}
     // and append it to the parent
         parent.appendChild(wrap);
     }
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent1">
        <div id="child1"></div><div id="child2"></div><div id="child3"></div><div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<! - If the child elements are one below the other in a separate row it works, if they are in one row it does not work ->
```

Comment: An element can only be in the DOM in one place. When you move the child into the wrapper, it disappears from the `.childNodes` list, so when you increment the loop index you skip an element.

Comment: You are mutating the array in your loop, it's shifting the indices. Maybe you want to copy the collection first: `for (const child of [...children])`

Comment: I just tested it, work, can you put as an answer to mark as the correct answer.

Comment: CherryDT, I just noticed that even empty elements get childless get a -wrap-of- div. I know it's not the primary question but how do you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep moving the first (index 0) entry, it will work. You need to add an offset when the wrong nodeType is encountered to skip over those ones, and if there are no child nodes then don't process the node:

```js
var container = document.getElementById("container");
const parentDivs = container.querySelectorAll(":scope *"); //if child elements also have child elements, to wrap in

for (let parent of parentDivs) {
    // create a new div
    if (parent.childNodes.length > 0) {
        let wrap = document.createElement('div');
        wrap.id = 'wrap-of-' + parent.id;
        // move the parent's children to it
        let children = parent.childNodes;
        
        const nChildren = children.length;
        let offset = 0;
    
        for (let i = 0; i < nChildren; i++) {
            if (children[offset].nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                children[offset].setAttribute("data", "somedata");
                wrap.append(children[offset]);
            } else {
                offset++;
            }
        }
        // and append it to the parent
        parent.appendChild(wrap);
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="parent1">
        <div id="child1"></div><div id="child2"></div><div id="child3"></div><div id="child4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, You managed to arrange the children elements and remove part of the warp-off if it is found in an empty element, you have completed the answer. I would ask you to explain why [offset]? .., I am new to javascript. Thank you

Comment: @deki0 As nodes that are not wanted (`.nodeType !== Node.ELEMENT_NODE`) are encountered, they will get left behind, so the first entry will no longer be the correct one to move.

Comment: Andrew, in this way as far as I understood, that if the parent or child is empty it does not put a wrap-of. How then to insert parent.innerHTML += parent.id; and children [offset] .innerHTML += children [offset] .id; before wrap-of div? I know it’s not the primary question, but it would complement, if possible.

Comment: @deki0 If I understand what you're asking, you could have an `else` clause for the `if (parent.childNodes.length > 0)` to add something if the node is empty.